# How to fix this encryption loop to read each character instead of first repeatedly

Tags: java

This is the version I'm working right now, where the loop does end but it just doesn't loop through each letter, instead it only repeats the first occurrence of the first letter.

For example, if `sourcetext` was `the ugly` and password was `ugly` it would repeat `4` (the position of `u`) four times (the length of ugly). Where as what I want it to do is repeat the loop four times (the length of ugly) but give back each position, not just the first (instead of `4444`, I'm getting `4 5 6 7`).

Am I using the wrong kind of loop to achieve this? I've tried a few different ways and at this point I am stuck. Also if the answer is really obvious please don't burn me at the stake, I've only been programming for three months and have really given it a go on my own.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
  String letter, sourcetext;
  Scanner sc;
  int temp;
  sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  sourcetext = sc.nextLine();
  letter = sc.nextLine();

  for (int i= 0; i < letter.length(); i++) { 
    temp = sourcetext.indexOf(letter);

    System.out.print(temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always use the same index: indexOf(letter). I guest what you want is:

```
for (int i= 0; i < letter.length(); i++) { 
    temp = sourcetext.indexOf(letter.charAt(i));

    System.out.print(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, your solution is good. For anyone who might read this and is looking for the same solution this is works with one minor adjustment. Without adding a space the decryption won't work.

Comment: Add a String variable like space = " " and then add that variable to the output like this System.out.print(space + temp).